# Linux inject C/C++ dll

Tags: c++, c, linux, inject

Ire any solutions available to inject in process own C/C++ dll and start from entrypoint, i need hook process socket send functions and paste my own code there. Is it available on linux?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `export LD_PRELOAD=your_so` or something completely different?

Comment: @skwllsp: I think PO asks about injecting into existing process. Kracken, to modify output to socket you can alternatively use PCap library

Comment: For injection at run-time check out Intel's PIN. It is a DBI framework which hides the details of the architecture. Other than that you could see Valgrind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical way to do it is to set the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable before launching the program. See for example [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/). Note though that some programs will disable this due to security reasons (it can snoop a passwords etc), e.g. gnupg prevents `LD_PRELOAD` from working.

If you want to inject into a running program it's much more difficult. It can be done with `ptrace` (e.g. attach with gdb and call dlopen). But it's unreliable because you don't know what state the program is when you attach.

Answer (score 0):

I made [pyinjector](https://github.com/kmaork/pyinjector), a tool you can use to inject a running process with a shared library.

To install, simply run `pip install pyinjector`.

Usage: `inject <pid> <dll_path>`